# Accessing context variables in modelform

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have a modelformset factory like so:

**Form:**

```
class AwesomeModelForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = AwesomeModel
        fields = ('thing', 'field_2', 'field_3')
        widgets = {
            'thing': HiddenInput(),
            }
```

**View:**

```
class AwesomeView(TemplateView):
    formset = modelformset_factory(AwesomeModel, form=AwesomeModelForm,
        can_delete=True)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        self.id = self.kwargs['id']
        self.thing = Thing.objects.get(id=self.id)
        formset = self.allocate_formset(queryset=AwesomeModel.objects\
            .filter(thing=self.thing))
        context = super(AllocateLeave, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formset'] = formset
        return context
```

I'd like to prepopulate the modelformset_factory using initial e.g.

```
formset = self.allocate_formset(queryset=AwesomeModel.objects.filter(thing=self.thing), initial=[{'thing': self.thing,}])
```

Django seems to think that the application of "initial" means the form has changed, so if I want to change a form value but not the 'extra' form, the validation fails because the 'extra' form is incomplete.
e.g.

```
for form in new_formset.forms:
    print form.has_changed()
```

returns True for the 'extra' field with the inital set and False if initial is not set in the formset declaration.

While iterating through the forms in the formset works to save each existing form, if I want to delete a form, or apply any formset wide validation, the form fails validation.

I think the solution might be to use a clean method for the 'thing' field, but I can't see how to access the context variables of the view in the modelform class. Is this the right approach or should I be pursuing another option?

Thanks

Comment: 'Django assumes that any form in a formset where "initial" is used has changed' : this is not true. If you think it is true, you should show a worked example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Really? OK it must just be me, but the issue remains. Will update question.